# Tricky sql query for popularity

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ProductId | BrandId | Views
    1         | 1       | 3
    2         | 1       | 2
    3         | 2       | 3
    4         | 2       | 4
```

Need write sql query to return this values:

```
BrandId | ViewsSummary
1       | 5
2       | 7
```

Please, how to do it?

Comment: Really looked it tricky? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hardly "tricky" - you're simply looking to *group* your results with an appropriate [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT BrandId, SUM(Views) AS ViewsSummary FROM my_table GROUP BY BrandId
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3358d/2/0).

Comment: Hell, I'm a fool. Thank you!